# Best practice for defining "constants" within top-level blocks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Normally, when a static value is used multiple times in a Ruby context, you'd define it as a constant. However, in some cases, the context is a block for some DSL at the top level of a source file (not within a module or class). I've run into this in various situations, but recently it's been ActiveAdmin:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  SOME_CONST_VALUE = 42
  ...
end
```

This works, but when Rails reloads the code, it leads to a lot of "already initialized constant" warnings. Also, it defines the constant on `Object` so it's available everywhere else in the entire app, which isn't what I want and is why [RuboCop has a lint for it](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/ConstantDefinitionInBlock).

Just using a local variable works, but it'd be nice to have constant semantics, and it doesn't look right, because you expect these kind of constants to use screaming snake case.

```rb
App.config do
  some_const_value = 42 # don't change me please :)
  ...
end
```

There's also the newish one-line method option, which makes it clear the value is constant, but isn't appropriate for operations you only want to do once, and still doesn't look like a constant:

```rb
App.config do
  def some_const_value = 42
  def _MAYBE_THIS = 43
  def config_params = YAML.load(File.read('config.yaml')) # oh wait, not like that

  def foo
    _MAYBE_THIS = some_const_value # maybe not
  end
end
```

Is there an accepted way to do this?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. Before you press the down-vote button because you see someone asking for "best practices", we have a concrete design problem here due to some peculiarities of the Ruby language.